# Adding controls to NSTextView and binding them to (ranges of) characters

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

When editing code, Xcode is capabale of displaying in-text controls, like drop down buttons which can show context menu's. I've seen other OS X apps that handle text capable of similar features. See the attached sample.

[image]

I presume this effect is obtained using `NSTextAttachmentCell` - although I'm not sure whether this is the proper way to implement this.

For my own app I would like to use this technique as well.

I have the following questions:

- Is `NSTextAttachmentCell` the correct way to implement such a feature? If not, what would be?
- How do I attach a control -comparable to the one in the above sample- to a specific range of text so that its location within `NSTextView` is dynamic and follows layout actions?

I found [this](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/ControlsMixedWithTextHowTo) which gives some hints but does not cover the attachment to specific text ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `NSTextAttachmentCell` will work, it has a disadvantage: the cell will become just a glyph in the text which was not what I wanted. It distorts the layout of the text, is selectable etc. I wanted the cell to be drawn over the text, just like the behaviour in Xcode.

The challenge was to find a way of translating a point from a Mouse Moved event to the position of a particular string of characters inside the `NSTextView`.

After some more digging I found a little gem in Apple's demo apps called [LayoutManagerDemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/LayoutManagerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). This demo shows a custom subclass of `NSTextView` capable of highlighting individual characters, words and lines while the mouse is hoovering its view. From there on it was pretty easy to fade in a button at the required `NSPoint` and then show a popup menu with some options.